# Database design - How does Salesforce store dynamically created fields on the fly?

Tags: database, salesforce

I am wondering how does Salesforce design their database to allow user to create dynamic fields.

I am looking to achieve this as well and will be interested to know if anyone have any idea how they did it.

Comment: you can always try and ask at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @glls Thanks for the information!

Comment: no problem @Norman

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good question for Stack Overflow. Hardly programming-related.

I'd say check if you really need to reinvent the wheel. If you want freestyle data storage - perhaps any of existing [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solutions will fit your needs. You probably have heard about MongoDB or BigTable (or whatever it is the hip kids do these days because "normal" relational databases are boring). You don't want to design by hand tables with placeholder columns of each appropriate type, then tables that would hold metadata for these (per client), then possibly some indexes on top of that...

This stuff **is** complex. That's what Salesforce clients pay for, to not have to worry about solving such problems (or hardware used. or scalability).

There must be some serious black magic going on behind the scenes when typically every SF record takes ~2KB of storage space, regardless of how complex it is (how many fields are used in the table). Don't expect to replicate their solution overnight.

But if you really want to try to dive into it - these might be a good start:

- [Force.com architecture overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture)
- [Review(?) of architecture](http://www.dbms2.com/2011/09/15/database-architecture-salesforce-com-force-com-and-database/) (but the whitepaper from 2008 the article talks about is a dead link. [Probably this is the right one](http://www.developerforce.com/media/ForcedotcomBookLibrary/Force.com_Multitenancy_WP_101508.pdf))
- [yet another article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/9/23/salesforce-architecture-how-they-handle-13-billion-transacti.html)

No idea if these will be terribly helpful... But at least you'll end up with list of keywords to go on with?

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will take a look at the links and see what I can get from there.